# Build error: bad reloc address

Tags: build, mingw, memory-address, intel-mkl, ipopt

I am trying to build IPopt with MKL blas on a 64 bit machine using MingW 64,
I can go through the configure process using the command below:

```
../configure ADD_FFLAGS=-fopenmp --with-blas="-L/c/intel/COMPOS~1/mkl/lib/intel64 \
-lmkl_intel_lp64_dll -lmkl_intel_thread_dll -lmkl_core_dll -Wl,\
--rpath,/c/intel/COMPOS~1/mkl/lib/intel64" \
--with-lapack="-L/c/intel/COMPOS~1/mkl/lib/intel64 \
-lmkl_intel_lp64_dll -lmkl_intel_thread_dll -lmkl_core_dll -Wl,\
--rpath,/c/intel/COMPOS~1/mkl/lib/intel64"
```

and I get successful configuration message, However when I try to proceed with "make" I get an error as below:

```
g++ -O3 -pipe -DNDEBUG -pedantic-errors -Wparentheses -Wreturn-type -Wcast-qual 
-Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-lon
g-long -DIPOPT_BUILD -o ipopt.exe ampl_ipopt.o -Wl,--rpath -Wl,"/c/intel/COMPOS~
1/mkl/lib/intel64" -Wl,--rpath -Wl,"/c/intel/COMPOS~1/mkl/lib/intel64" -Wl,--rpa
th -Wl,"/c/intel/COMPOS~1/mkl/lib/intel64" -Wl,--rpath -Wl,"/c/intel/COMPOS~1/mk
l/lib/intel64" -Wl,--rpath -Wl,"/c/intel/COMPOS~1/mkl/lib/intel64"  ./.libs/libi
poptamplinterface.a ../../Interfaces/.libs/libipopt.a /home/Kevin/mybuild/coin
ipopt/build_64_intel/ThirdParty/ASL/.libs/libcoinasl.a /home/Kevin/mybuild/coi
nipopt/build_64_intel/ThirdParty/Mumps/.libs/libcoinmumps.a -L/c/intel/COMPOS~1/
mkl/lib/intel64 -Lc:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1 -Lc:/mingw6
4/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../.
./x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -Lc:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4
.7.1/../../../../lib -Lc:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../
../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -Lc:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.
1/../../.. /home/Kevin/mybuild/coinipopt/build_64_intel/ThirdParty/HSLold/.lib
s/libcoinhsl.a -lgfortran -lgomp -lmingwthrd -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lmoldname -lming
wex -lmsvcrt -lquadmath -lpthread -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 /home
/Kevin/mybuild/coinipopt/build_64_intel/ThirdParty/Metis/.libs/libcoinmetis.a 
-lmkl_intel_lp64_dll -lmkl_intel_thread_dll -lmkl_core_dll
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/libgcc.a(unwind-sjlj.o): In f
unction `_Unwind_SjLj_Register':
c:\crossdev\build\gcc-tdm64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\libgcc/../../../../src/gcc-4.7.1/
libgcc/unwind-sjlj.c:127: multiple definition of `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/libgcc_s.a(d000017.o):(.text+
0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/libgcc.a(unwind-sjlj.o): In f
unction `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister':
c:\crossdev\build\gcc-tdm64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\libgcc/../../../../src/gcc-4.7.1/
libgcc/unwind-sjlj.c:174: multiple definition of `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/libgcc_s.a(d000020.o):(.text+
0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/libgcc.a(unwind-sjlj.o): In f
unction `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume':
c:\crossdev\build\gcc-tdm64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\libgcc/../../../../src/gcc-4.7.1/
libgcc/unwind.inc:220: multiple definition of `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/libgcc_s.a(d000018.o):(.text+
0x0): first defined here
c:/intel/COMPOS~1/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(_dgetrf_lp64.obj):(.tex
t[dgetrf]+0xb4): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
c:/intel/COMPOS~1/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(_dgetrf_lp64.obj):(.tex
t[dgetrf]+0xf5): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
c:/intel/COMPOS~1/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(_dgetrf_lp64.obj):(.xda
ta+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw3
2/bin/ld.exe: c:/intel/COMPOS~1/mkl/lib/intel64/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib(_dgetrf_l
p64.obj): bad reloc address 0x1 in section `.text[DGETRF]'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [ipopt.exe] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/Kevin/mybuild/coinipopt/build_64_intel/Ipopt
/src/Apps/AmplSolver'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/Kevin/mybuild/coinipopt/build_64_intel/Ipopt
/src/Apps'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/Kevin/mybuild/coinipopt/build_64_intel/Ipopt
'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I would be thankful if somebody could help with it.

Follow Up: I think I found what the error stems from,
when running configure, it goes back to the shared library of MKL and gets its path as (available in the configure log file):

```
/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Intel/Shared Libraries/redist/intel64/compiler
```

which indeed its not a short path! so I guess this is raising the problem but I don't know how to force configure get short path! In addition, I am using Windows 8 64 bit, despite enabling 8.3 naming convention (Reg. Key set to 0) still I only get 8.3 name for some directories for example I don't get short path for Program Files and Program Files (x86).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer:
Intel MKL for windows does not provide compatibility with gnu compilers available with MingW!
Switched to OpenBlas and it was sorted.

Special Thanks goes to Tony Kelman.